# Change $mailTo variable based on select input value (array)

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following select list:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <select name="foo" id="foo">
        <option value="sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="salesAssist">Sales Assist</option>
        <option value="billing">Billing</option>
        <option value="billingAssist">Billing Assist</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I need to route the `$mailTo` variable depending on which option they select, `Sales` and `Sales Assist` go to `sales@email.com`, while `Billing` and `Billing Assist` go to `billing@email.com`.

PHP pseudeo code!

```
<? php 
   $_POST['foo'] if inArray(sales, salesAssist) foo="sales@email.com";
    else if inArray(billing, billingAssist) foo="billing@email.com";
   mailTo="foo"
?>
```

I know there is nothing correct about the above, but you can see what I am trying to do, change a variable's value based on the selected value. I don't want to do this with JavaScript, I would rather learn more PHP here.

Comment: its so close why dont you convert the pseudo to real code? http://us2.php.net//manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: I am having issues with syntax. I know what I want it to do, but can't get it right. Bad me. Damnit, didn't see your link. Thank you very much. Trust me man, I have been trying.

Comment: only bad for not trying

Comment: and i think you need to lean the php email function `mail()` as well

Comment: JakeGould - so why did you feel the need to go in and edit my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudocode is pretty much right on. Here is an implementation, using [**in_array()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
if (in_array($_POST['foo'], array('sales', 'salesAssit')) {
    $foo = 'sales@email.com';
}
elseif (in_array($_POST['foo'], array('billing', 'billingAssit')) {
    $foo = 'billing@email.com';
}
```

Of course, there are other ways to go about this. With only two values to search for, you could also do something like this:

```
if ($_POST['foo'] == 'sales' || $_POST['foo'] == 'salesAssit') {
    $foo = 'sales@email.com';
}
elseif ($_POST['foo'] == 'billing' || $_POST['foo'] == 'billingAssit') {
    $foo = 'billing@email.com';
}
```

Or, just check for the occurrence of the 'billing' or 'sales', using [**strpos()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if (strpos($_POST['foo'], 'sales') !== false) {
    $foo = 'sales@email.com';
}
elseif (strpos($_POST['foo'], 'billing') !== false) {
    $foo = 'billing@email.com';
}
```

However, what I like to do in situations like these, where you know it will always be one option or the other, is assign one as the default, and only change it if necessary:

```
$foo = 'sales@email.com';
if (strpos($_POST['foo'], 'billing') !== false) {
    $foo = 'billing@email.com';
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks you Mark.

Comment: @JakeGould A better question would be, why create an array and use `array_key_exists` when this is a problem simply solved by `strpos`?

Comment: @JakeGould We'll have to agree to disagree. I don't think your method is more readable at all - I would argue the opposite. Maybe in a situation where there were lots and lots of emails to go through, your method might be preferable, but with just the two, I see no reason to add the additional complexity, especially at double the processing time. (Ya the difference in seconds is insignificant, but it's still 50% slower). The one benefit I see to your method is it can be easily expanded later on to include more emails. +1 for that, although I still think mine is the better solution here ;P

Comment: First off, thank you Mark M for the great answers and examples. Sorry someone had to come in and hijack this question. I really appreciate the help, you answered exactly what I asked and gave other alternatives. thanks!

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign You unaccepted... mind if I ask why?

Comment: Left screen open, kids like to click around. Sorry man, internet points restored!

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return $needle === "" || strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}

if(startsWith($_POST["foo"], "sales") {
    $foo = "sales@email.com";
} else if(startsWith($_POST["foo"], "billing") {
    $foo = "billing@email.com";
}
```

Comment: That is awesome, I need to look into 'startsWith' and the haystack, needle. I have a very rough understanding of those. Thank you, this is something more advanced than I needed and great to learn from

Comment: You're welcome, good luck for the next steps of your project !

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, sir by using and array of e-mail values which you then cross check with [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).

```
// Set an array of e-mails.
$email_array = array();
$email_array['sales'] = "sales@email.com";
$email_array['salesAssist'] = "sales@email.com";
$email_array['billing'] = "billing@email.com";
$email_array['billingAssist'] = "billing@email.com";

// Do basic checks on 'foo'. If not? It's null.
$foo = isset($_POST['foo']) && !empty($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : null;

// Now check if 'foo' is in the array. If not? It's null.
$mailTo = !empty($foo) && array_key_exists($foo, $email_array) ? $email_array[$foo] : null;
```

The benefit of doing it this way is it’s clean & simple. You can set any e-mail you want in the array. And you can even set a default—instead of `null`—if you wish if somehow the script gets returned with none of the options selected.

Or if ternary logic seems confusing & you would rather just act on the data right away, this will work:

```
// Do basic checks on 'foo'. And check if 'foo' is in the array. If not? It's null.
$mailTo = null;
if ((isset($_POST['foo']) && !empty($_POST['foo'])) && array_key_exists($_POST['foo'], $email_array)) {
  $mailTo = $email_array[$foo];
}
```